# SSH library как собрать?

Tags: windows, qt, ssh, сборка

Мне нужно собрать и использовать в QT под Windows.

Исходники: https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/snapshot/master.zip

У меня возникает ошибка при компиляции

```
No rule to make target 'C:/Windows/System32/libcrypto.dll', needed by 'src/libssh.dll'.  Stop.
```

Но этот файл есть в той директории.

Comment: укажите, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, какую фразу из [инструкции](https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git/tree/INSTALL) вам не удалось перевести.